# Portable WCF Test Client 10 (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: .net, wcf, wcftestclient

I'm trying to get WCF test client 10 (included in VS 2010) on a server that doesn't have Visual Studio installed.  I was able to find file packages for version 9, but not 10.  These packages included the following files:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.VirtualTreeGrid.dll*
- SvcUtil.exe*
- SvcUtil.exe.config
- WcfSvcHost.exe
- WcfWvcHost.exe.config
- WcfTestClient.exe*
- WcfTestClient.exe.config

I read that only the files marked with * are required.  I tried to copy the versions of these files from my machine (which has VS 2010 installed) to a folder on the destination machine, but when I run WcfTestClient.exe, I get the following error:

> To run this application, you first must install one of the following
>   versions of the .NET Framework:
>
> v4.0.30319
>
> Contact your application
>   publisher for instructions about obtaining the appropriate version of
>   the .NET Framework.

It seems like it's looking for .NET 4, which we haven't migrated our apps to yet.  I tried with the SvcUtil.exe from both of the following locations:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

But neither worked.

I also added the following registry keys (because of [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c3c7221c-c06f-4364-887a-fb20f22877be/wcf-test-client-problem)):

- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
  SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x64] "InstallationFolder"="\"
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
  SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86] "InstallationFolder"="\"

I'm hoping there's a dll somewhere that the client depends on that I can add to the folder?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

How about if you download it from here instead?

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/workandstudybook/archive/2014/06/03/standalone-wcftestclient.aspx